# Find flash element in Selenium for JUnit Test

Tags: flash, selenium, junit

I am trying to find a flash element within our site that is dynamically created on a per user basis and I am struggling trying to get Selenium to identify the element.

Below is the HTML for the site.

```
<div style="height:380px;" id="CustomerMenu">

<object height="100%" width="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://genericdemoplus42.dataimpact.com/swf/ApplicationMenu.swf" id="menuSwfDiv" style="visibility: visible;">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="flashvars" value="txtUsrInfo=ebe5B48ogm9c44NmC0oE4wMytr1I2R1R8u0lQaXihXqBrOlRP6LPt5tpLssc%2FIcuDal3QYNG3L0uP6t0b1VO0XdcByfG3tk%2FTWuTHFML5ljYkiA0%2FSlGr7f1M1vn7v1mWKIY1H0jayn21uojVZr1NQ%3D%3D&amp;txtCustomLocalDir=7QPTAq5jW6oZtSKXJvog%2bg%3d%3d&amp;txtServerDir=j7wD07B866hSgtgma%2fJLHMJue5CbIxhM6MzVY8KSCs0%3d&amp;txtWebServerUrl=https://website.com/&amp;txtWebCustomUrl=https://site.com/&amp;txtCustomerId=ACv4Qsx9%2freYK6%2bRI8n0%2fw%3d%3d&amp;txtAssetUrl=https://assets.site.com/Assets/site42/"></object></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Flash element can be found like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//object[@type='application/x-shockwave-flash']"))
```

Comment: This didn't work since I am not using WebDriver  I did try the following code, but it still isn't finding it:

Comment: int matchingCountTotal = 0; 
    matchingCountTotal += selenium.getXpathCount("//object[@type='application/x-shockwave-flash']").intValue();
  
    assertTrue("Flash objects found.",matchingCountTotal>0);

Comment: Weird. I verified that XPath finds the flash element on you HTML. The problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: Another user is having similar problems with getXpathCount() [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673009/getxpathcount-does-not-work)